# Sort emails by sender on iOS

Tags: ios, mail.app, email

It is possible to sort emails by sender (“From”) using Mail app on Mac.

Can the native mail app do this on iPhone and iPad?

Comment: I’ve edited this to have one question. Feel free to ask a second question on software recommendations if you want.

Comment: @bmike thanks! As long as it is accepted here, I will ask about recommendations if it turned out not possible to sort by sender with the iOS built-in Mail app.

Comment: Indeed - guidance on recommendations is here if you find people don’t respond to the first try. https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation? I think this use case will be an excellent recommendation question to have on the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - you would need to search the mailbox and filter on the sender. At that point, you have the sort for just that one From sorted by order received.